# Disposing of subclasses

Tags: c#, singleton, abstract-class, idisposable

As part of a library assembly I’ve got an abstract class `SignalGenerator` that implements `IDisposable` and has several subclasses. Within this abstract class I maintain static instances of each singleton subclass:

```
    private static volatile Lazy<SignalGenerator> s_signalGenerator; // Default object instance if subclass not specified.
    private static volatile Lazy<SignalGenerator> s_signalGeneratorSimulated;
    private static volatile Lazy<SignalGenerator> s_signalGenerator79C3;
    private static volatile Lazy<SignalGenerator> s_signalGenerator75C3;
    private static volatile Lazy<SignalGenerator> s_signalGenerator41620;
```

I have a separate assembly that references this one and creates the subclass instances by calling a static `SignalGenerator.GetInstance(className)` method which instantiates one of the above class variables, based on the `className` parameter.

The issue now is figuring out which subclass to dispose of when a call is made to the abstract’s class `Dispose()` method:

```
   using SignalGenerator s = SignalGenerator.GetInstance(nameof(P41620)); // P41620 is a subclass of SignalGenerator and corresponds to s_signalGenerator41620.
   s.Dispose(); // How to tell abstract class which subclass to dispose of when Dispose doesn’t accept parameters?
```

I thought I had this figured out by adding the following method to the abstract class and overriding it in the subclasses:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing, [CallerFilePath] string subclassName = "")
```

Where `CallerFilePath` could be parsed to find the calling subclass name. But this only works if the subclass overrides this Dispose method, and not all do.

I realize the whole thing has a bit of code smell to it so am looking for better solutions.

Comment: I think there is a problem with this approach is that _you shouldn't allow callers to destroy **singleton objects**_.  If you controll creation of the objects you should control deletion and not the callers.  Otherwise you could end up disposing an object leaving ophaned disposed objects elsewhere

Comment: Nothing says you can't dispose of singletons, just that you can't create more than one instance.

Comment: If you allow it its technically no longer a singleton.  If two callers get the same instance and one of the callers calls `Dispose` the other caller will crash next time they go to use their reference.  You have _pulled the rug out_ from the other caller

Comment: That's why I keep an instance counter and only dispose when it reaches zero. That requires the rest of the code to call dispose of course.